# Linq (Visual Basic) - Comparing two anonymous types yields no results

Tags: vb.net, linq

I am trying to write a linq query with a composite key. Here is the full query:

```
    Dim qeRelationships = From p In qualificationElements _
                          Join r In relationships On New With {.ElementCode = r.Parent, .Type = r.ParentType} _
                                              Equals New With {.ElementCode = p.ElementCode, .Type = p.Type} _
                          Join c In qualificationElements On New With {.ElementCode = r.Child, .Type = r.ChildType} _
                                                      Equals New With {.ElementCode = c.ElementCode, .Type = c.Type} _
                          Select New QualificationElementRelationship _
                                 With {.Parent = p, _
                                       .Child = c, _
                                       .Relationship = r.RelationshipType, _
                                       .Scope = r.Scope}
```

This is yielding no results and I am not sure why.

I have boiled it down to two examples. The following works and returns records:

```
    Dim qeRelationships = From p In qualificationElements _
                          Join r In relationships On r.Child Equals p.ElementCode _
                          Select New _
                                 With {.Relationship = r.RelationshipType, _
                                       .Scope = r.Scope}
```

This next snippet does not work and does not return records

```
    Dim qeRelationships = From p In qualificationElements _
                          Join r In relationships On New With {.a = r.Child} Equals New With {.a = p.ElementCode} _
                          Select New _
                                 With {.Relationship = r.RelationshipType, _
                                       .Scope = r.Scope}
```

Why does the first query work and the second fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick post and answer! It is because all the properties of your anonymous class need to be marked up with the "Key" directive.

```
    Dim qeRelationships = From p In qualificationElements _
                          Join r In relationships On New With {Key .a = r.Child} Equals New With {Key .a = p.ElementCode} _
                          Select New _
                                 With {.Relationship = r.RelationshipType, _
                                       .Scope = r.Scope}
```

The full query

```
    Dim qeRelationships = From p In qualificationElements _
                          Join r In relationships On New With {Key .ElementCode = r.Parent, Key .Type = r.ParentType} _
                                              Equals New With {Key .ElementCode = p.ElementCode, Key .Type = p.Type} _
                          Join c In qualificationElements On New With {Key .ElementCode = r.Child, Key .Type = r.ChildType} _
                                                      Equals New With {Key .ElementCode = c.ElementCode, Key .Type = c.Type} _
                          Select New QualificationElementRelationship _
                                 With {.Parent = p, _
                                       .Child = c, _
                                       .Relationship = r.RelationshipType, _
                                       .Scope = r.Scope}
```